# nvd3 linebar chart y2axis time format issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a working linebarchart and I am trying to do the following:

- Have the y2axis on the right be representative of the time in
  hh:mm:ss
- The black line should be representative of the time
- The bars should be representative of the yAxis on the left

I am using the following code to change the y2axis to time format:

```
      chart.y2Axis
          .tickFormat(function(d) {
              return d3.time.format('%H:%M:%S')(new Date(d))  
      });
```

As a result of this change for some reason the bar value shows the time value whereas it should show the contact value.

Also, when mousing over the black line it should show the time value.

Full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b4u2unoL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following nvd3 library:

```
http://nvd3.org/assets/js/nv.d3.js
```

and

```
http://nvd3.org/assets/css/nv.d3.css
```

I picked these up form the [demo site](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html)

The CDN is not updated with the latest code used in the demo.

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrcjp79o/)